# KVM guest connected to bridge can only communicate with host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, bridge, linux-kvm

UPDATE:
Changed host from mint to ubuntu now it works fine

I have a linux mint host machine with a network bridge with a static IP Address. Here is the bridge:
[image]
I have an Ubuntu guest created in Virtual Machine Manager that has a virtual network interface with the network source being the bridge.

[image]

On my host machine, I can connect to the bridge just fine and I am able to communicate with the router, But on the guest machine, I cannot get an IP address through DHCP (the guest keeps saying "Activation Of Network Failed"). For testing purposes, I assigned the guest a static IP which allows the guest to ping the host and vice versa, but the guest cannot communicate with the outside network.

Host To Guest:

[image]

Guest To Host:

[image]

Guest To Default Gateway:

[image]

Also, when I set a static IP, the network logo has a question mark seen here:
[image]

I have disabled the firewall on the host and guest machines by running `sudo ufw disable` to see if that would work, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Whenever the guest pings a node on the network, the MAC and IP address of the node is added to the ARP table - but the pings fail with 'destination host unreachable'.

I have added the following to the /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

This doesn't do anything either.

Wireshark On Bridge:
[image]

Wireshark On Remote Client:
[image]

The guest is sending the ping requests but is not receiving the responses from another computer on the LAN.

Thanks For Your Help!

Comment: Can you try boot another VM (just any live iso should do) and see the *VMs* can reach each others?

Comment: @TomYan I created two ubuntu vms and they can ping each other aswell as ping the host, but they cannot ping any nodes on the network (even though their macs get added to the arp table which is strange)

Comment: Does `ip l set enp6s0 promisc on` help? (Btw by `arp table` do you mean arp tables on the "nodes on the network"?)

Comment: @TomYan unfortunately setting it to promiscuous mode doesn't help. By arp table, i mean when i ping a machine on the local network using a VM, I don't get a response but when i run `arp -a` it produces a result which shows the IP address that i pinged with the mac address of the device, i guess meaning ARP packets are being let through but ping packets are not being let through.

Comment: Maybe if possible you should `tcpdump` (or equivalent) on the VM host and a node. (Or, ping a VM from a node and `tcpdump` on the VM host.) Have you confirmed it isn't just your LAN devices ignore ping? What kind of switch / router are you using in your LAN btw? Is it a typical consumer-grade one?

Comment: @TomYan so i have wireshark monitoring the bridge and wireshark running on another machine. (I can ping this machine from the host just fine). When i ping this machine from the guest, wireshark monitoring the bridge shows the ICMP ping request packet being sent, but it does not see the reply. However, on the other machine, I can see the ICMP ping request and reply being sent. So for some reason the ping reply is being sent through the network but the bridge is not receiving it. I can only guess that the host is dropping the packets because of some sort of firewall rule, but ufw is disabled.

Comment: @TomYan i have unmanaged switches and a consumer router. I can also see ICMP "Destination unreachable (port unreachable)" packets being sent from the bridge to the gateway.

Comment: `When i ping this machine from the guest, wireshark monitoring the bridge shows the ICMP ping request packet being sent, but it does not see the reply. However, on the other machine, I can see the ICMP ping request and reply being sent.` This sounds more and more like some kind of problem with the NIC of the VM host (e.g. because of a driver issue or so it can't actually enter promiscuous mode). I have never experienced something like that though so I'm not entirely sure if that could actually happen.

Comment: @TomYan thanks for your help. I really appreciate it and I think you might be correct. I switched my host OS from mint to ubuntu and it works perfectly now.